# OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable. What causes this?

Tags: python, pipe, fifo

**Background**

I have two python processes that need to communicate with each other. The comminication is handled by a class named Pipe. I made a seperate class for this because most of the information that needs to be communicated comes in the form of dictionaries so Pipe implements a pretty simple protocol for doing this.

Here is the Pipe constructor:

```
def __init__(self,sPath):
    """
    create the fifo. if it already exists just associate with it
    """
    self.sPath = sPath
    if not os.path.exists(sPath):
        try:
            os.mkfifo(sPath)
        except:
            raise Exception('cannot mkfifo at path \n {0}'.format(sPath))
    self.iFH = os.open(sPath,os.O_RDWR | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    self.iFHBlocking = os.open(sPath,os.O_RDWR)
```

So ideally I would just construct a Pipe in each process with the same path and they would be able to talk nice.

I'm going to skip out stuff about the protocol because I think it is largely unnecessary here.

All read and write operations make use of the following 'base' functions:

```
def base_read_blocking(self,iLen):
    self.lock()
    lBytes = os.read(self.iFHBlocking,iLen)
    self.unlock()
    return lBytes

def base_read(self,iLen):
    print('entering base read')
    self.lock()
    lBytes = os.read(self.iFH,iLen)
    self.unlock()
    print('exiting base read')
    return lBytes

def base_write_blocking(self,lBytes):
    self.lock()
    safe_write(self.iFHBlocking,lBytes)
    self.unlock()

def base_write(self,lBytes):
    print('entering base write')
    self.lock()
    safe_write(self.iFH,lBytes)
    self.unlock()
    print('exiting base write')
```

safe_write was suggested in another post

```
def safe_write(*args, **kwargs):
    while True:
        try:
            return os.write(*args, **kwargs)
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno == 35:
                import time
                print(".")
                time.sleep(0.5)
            else:
                raise
```

locking and unlocking is handled like this:

```
def lock(self):
    print('locking...')
    while True:
        try:
            os.mkdir(self.get_lock_dir())
            print('...locked')
            return
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno != 17:
                raise e

def unlock(self):
    try:
        os.rmdir(self.get_lock_dir())
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != 2:
            raise e
    print('unlocked')
```

**The Problem**

This *sometimes* happens:

```
....in base_read
lBytes = os.read(self.iFH,iLen)
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Sometimes it's fine.

**The Magical Solution**

I seem to have stopped the problem from happening. Please note this is not me answering my own question. My question is explained in the next section.

I changed the read functions to look more like this and it sorted stuff out:

```
def base_read(self,iLen):
    while not self.ready_for_reading():
        import time
        print('.')
        time.sleep(0.5)

    lBytes = ''.encode('utf-8')
    while len(lBytes)<iLen:
        self.lock()
        try:
            lBytes += os.read(self.iFH,iLen)
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno == 11:
                import time
                print('.')
                time.sleep(0.5)
        finally:
            self.unlock()
        return lBytes


def ready_for_reading(self):
    lR,lW,lX = select.select([self.iFH,],[],[],self.iTimeout)
    if not lR:
        return False
    lR,lW,lX = select.select([self.iFHBlocking],[],[],self.iTimeout)
    if not lR:
        return False
    return True
```

**The Question**

I'm struggling to find out exactly why it is temporarily unavailable. The two processes cannot access the actual named pipe at the same time due to the locking mechanism (unless I am mistaken?) so is this due to something more fundamental to fifos that my program is not taking into account?

All I really want is an explanation... The solution I found works but it looks like magic. Can anyone offer an explanation?

**System**

- Ubuntu 12.04,
- Python3.2.3

Comment: not handling multiple pipe is causing this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a [similar problem with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384000/java-io-ioexception-error-11) before. Have a look at the accepted answer--- the problem was that I was creating new threads in a loop. I suggest you have a look at the code creating the pipe and make sure you are not creating multiple pipes.

Comment: The point is to create multiple Pipes. So process A makes a Pipe and process B makes a pipe with the same path. Then process A can say `pipe.write(some_dictionary)` and process B can say `some_dictionary = pipe.read()`

Comment: also, if the problem was the number of things running then putting in a sleep() call wouldn't fix things. Unless I'm missing something...