# Why Git gives the error "Resource temporarily unavailable (code: 11)" when simultaneously executing multiple instances?

Tags: linux, git, version-control, nim-lang, git-init

I have an automated test that tries to clone a bunch of specific revisions from the local Git repository by using the following asynchronous Nim procedure.

```
proc cloneSpecificRevision(downloadMethod: DownloadMethod,
                           url, downloadDir: string,
                           vcsRevision: Sha1Hash) {.async.} =
  assert vcsRevision != notSetSha1Hash
  display("Cloning", "revision: " & $vcsRevision, priority = MediumPriority)
  case downloadMethod
  of DownloadMethod.git:
    let downloadDir = downloadDir.quoteShell
    createDir(downloadDir)
    discard await tryDoCmdExAsync("git", @["-C", downloadDir, "init"])
    discard await tryDoCmdExAsync("git",
      @["-C", downloadDir, "remote", "add", "origin", url])
    discard await tryDoCmdExAsync("git",
      @["-C", downloadDir, "fetch", "--depth", "1", "origin", $vcsRevision])
    discard await tryDoCmdExAsync("git",
      @["-C", downloadDir, "reset", "--hard", "FETCH_HEAD"])
  of DownloadMethod.hg:
    discard await tryDoCmdExAsync("hg", @["clone", url, "-r", $vcsRevision])
```

The result is

```
Downloading /tmp/tlockfile/origins/dep1 using git
    Cloning revision: 8b6ce61df05f4e21ad954f9ddb487eda8fb64f41
  Executing git -C /tmp/nimble_94295/_tmptlockfileoriginsdep1_0.1.0_8b6ce61df05f4e21ad954f9ddb487eda8fb64f41 init
Downloading /tmp/tlockfile/origins/dep2 using git
    Cloning revision: d1ba2f37a1647ca1ed804dfa0c8c73a7de98201e
  Executing git -C /tmp/nimble_94295/_tmptlockfileoriginsdep2_0.1.0_d1ba2f37a1647ca1ed804dfa0c8c73a7de98201e init
    Error:  Resource temporarily unavailable (code: 11)
```

The used Git version is:

```
> git --version
git version 2.31.1
```

The problem happens only on Linux and my tests are passing normally on Windows and macOS systems. What can be the reason for this problem?

Comment: This message comes from a tool other than Git, since Git doesn't produce output like that.  What tool is that, and how does it work if you clone the repository by hand?

Comment: @bk2204 It has to be from Git because I don't use other tools in this test. I added some additional logging with the exact command which is being executed.

Comment: @bk2204 The problem happens when I try to execute in parallel two asynchronous Git commands.

Answer (score 1):

Error 11 on Linux is `EAGAIN`, `Resource temporarily unavailable`.  The Linux `fork` system call is probably producing this error because, well, there are not enough *resources* at the moment.

What's a resource?  There are a lot of them, but one of them is memory and another is processes.  Both can be "temporarily" used up since programs (processes) run for a while, then exit; when they exit, they release the resources they were using.  See also [Fork fails with "resource temporarily unavailable". Which resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44081295/1256452), [OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable. What causes this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13340893/1256452), and [fork() failing with Out of memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15608347/1256452) (note that the last one shows errno 12, `ENOMEM`, but you can get `EAGAIN` on other Unix-like systems here so I've included it even though you mentioned Linux specifically).

Note that this has nothing to do with Git itself: if you've hit a process limit with `fork`, it won't matter what you intend to run *after* the `fork` returns in the child process.

Comment: Well, is there some way to overcome this issue? I started only two simultaneous Git processes. I don't understand how is possible to hit the limit. Even more, the code was working some time ago.

Comment: You'll need to figure out *what the system is running out of* (is it processes? what are your limit settings?) See the other questions.

Comment: Any idea how to determine what the system is running out of?

Comment: Hopefully some of the related questions have ways of finding out. Follow up with them.

Comment: @bobeff You could try [increasing the different limits tweakable through the ulimit command](https://linuxhint.com/linux_ulimit_command/). Try setting everything to unlimited, and if that works, backtrack to see which limit was holding you down (or just leave unlimited for your test suite).